# Null all references of custom element being removed from the DOM in disconnectedCallback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, custom-element

I have a custom element offering an API method `sayHello`. I need to "destroy" all references to the custom element in the `disconnectedCallback` if the element gets removed from the DOM. How can I achieve this?

```js
class RemoveEl extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.type= 'button';
    this.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
    })
  }
  
  sayHello() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
  
  disconnectedCallback() {
    if (!document.body.contains(this)) {
      console.log('removed');
      // here I need something like 
      // this = null;
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('remove-el', RemoveEl, { extends: 'button' });

var sayHello = document.getElementById('sayHello');
var removeEl = document.getElementById('removeEl');

sayHello.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (removeEl) {
    removeEl.sayHello();
  }
})
```

```html
<div>Test:
  <button is="remove-el" id="removeEl">Click to remove</button>
  <button id="sayHello" type="button">Say Hello</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, as long as you hold a reference to your element on the JavaScript side, the garbage collector won't be able to destroy your element, even if it was removed from the DOM. Your element will still be live and you will be able to call methods on it.

You will have to manage the references yourself. In the `disconnectedCallback` of your custom element, set a property to mark it deleted, for example: `this.destroyed = true`.

Then you can use that property to safeguard the access, but the element won't be garbage collected:

```js
class RemoveEl extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.type= 'button';
    this.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
    })
  }
  
  sayHello() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
  
  disconnectedCallback() {
    if (!document.body.contains(this)) {
      this.destroyed = true;
      console.log('removed');
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('remove-el', RemoveEl, { extends: 'button' });

const sayHello = document.getElementById('sayHello');
const removeEl = document.getElementById('removeEl');

sayHello.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (removeEl && !removeEl.destroyed) {
    removeEl.sayHello();
  }
})
```

```html
<div>Test:
  <button is="remove-el" id="removeEl">Click to remove</button>
  <button id="sayHello" type="button">Say Hello</button>
</div>
```

Or create a reference wrapper on which you can apply functions only if the inner reference is valid, still garbage collection won't be able to destroy the reference since there is now a closure over it due to the `do` function using `el`:

```js
class RemoveEl extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.type= 'button';
    this.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
    })
  }
  
  sayHello() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
  
  disconnectedCallback() {
    if (!document.body.contains(this)) {
      this.destroyed = true;
      console.log('removed');
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('remove-el', RemoveEl, { extends: 'button' });

const ref = el => ({ do: fn => { if (el && !el.destroyed) fn(el); }  })

const sayHello = document.getElementById('sayHello');
const removeEl = ref(document.getElementById('removeEl'));

sayHello.addEventListener('click', () => {
 removeEl.do(el => el.sayHello());
})
```

```html
<div>Test:
  <button is="remove-el" id="removeEl">Click to remove</button>
  <button id="sayHello" type="button">Say Hello</button>
</div>
```

Or you could use a proxy to manage that reference. As long as `destroyed` is false, the methods would be called on the object, but as soon as the proxy detects that `destroyed = true`, it would return a default value for the properties and destroy its own reference to the element, which hopefully will let the garbage collector get rid of it.

Something a bit like this:

```js
class RemoveEl extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.type= 'button';
    this.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
    })
  }
  
  sayHello() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
  
  disconnectedCallback() {
    if (!document.body.contains(this)) {
      this.destroyed = true;
      console.log('removed');
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('remove-el', RemoveEl, { extends: 'button' });

const ref = (el, defaultEl) => {
  let destroyed = el.destroyed;
  const checkEl = () => {
    if (!destroyed && el && el.destroyed) {
      destroyed = true;
      el = null;
    }
    return destroyed;
  }
  return new Proxy({}, {
    get: (obj, prop) => {
      return checkEl() ? defaultEl[prop] : el[prop];
    }
  });
}

const sayHello = document.getElementById('sayHello');
const removeEl = ref(document.getElementById('removeEl'), { sayHello: () => console.log('bye') });

sayHello.addEventListener('click', () => {
  removeEl.sayHello();
})
```

```html
<div>Test:
  <button is="remove-el" id="removeEl">Click to remove</button>
  <button id="sayHello" type="button">Say Hello</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually even in the 3rd solution the button won't be destroyed because of the reference added in the ref function signature (el)

Comment: Setting the reference to null will release it from the function scope

Comment: Yes but this will occur only after one of its method is called after being removed from the DOM (which may occur later or never), not immediately after disconnectedCallback.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 solutions:

**Don't keep any references**

The way the custom element will be garbaged collected as soon as it is removed from the DOM.

```
//var removeEl = document.getElementById('removeEl');

sayHello.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let removeEl = document.getElementById('removeEl')
    if ( removeEl )
        removeEl.sayHello();   
})
```

**Manage global references**

If you need to keep a global reference to you custom element, you'll need to set it to null to get the object destroyed.

You can achieve this by many ways. For example, dispach a custom event when the element is disconneced and process it at the reference level.

```js
class RemoveEl extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('click', () => this.parentElement.removeChild(this));
  }
  
  sayHello() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
  
  disconnectedCallback() {
    console.log('removed');
    //dispatch a destroy event
    var ev = new CustomEvent('destroyed');
    document.dispatchEvent(ev);
  }
}

customElements.define('remove-el', RemoveEl, { extends: 'button' });

var sayHello = document.getElementById('sayHello');
var removeEl = document.getElementById('removeEl');
//delete reference
document.addEventListener('destroyed', () => removeEl = null);

sayHello.addEventListener('click', () => removeEl && removeEl.sayHello())
```

```html
<button is="remove-el" id="removeEl">Click to remove</button>
<button id="sayHello">Say Hello</button>
```